# Installed MariaDB 5.5.52 from RPM, MariaDB 5.5.59 gets installed

Tags: centos, mariadb

I have a database server with MariaDB 5.5.52:

```
[root@sql01 ~]# yum list installed|grep 5.5.52-1.el7
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
mariadb.x86_64                    1:5.5.52-1.el7                       @base
mariadb-libs.x86_64               1:5.5.52-1.el7                       @CentOS
mariadb-server.x86_64             1:5.5.52-1.el7                       @base
[root@sql01 ~]# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.52-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

I need to install that very same version on a new server, but MariaDB gets shipped as MariaDB 5.5.59 for new installs. So, I got an RPM and installed it as follows:

```
wget http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.52/yum/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-5.5.52-centos7-x86_64-server.rpm
yum install MariaDB-5.5.52-centos7-x86_64-server.rpm
```

Even though this is an RPM for 5.5.52, 5.5.59 gets installed:

```
[root@db01 ~]# yum list installed|grep 5.5.52-1.el7
MariaDB-server.x86_64                 5.5.52-1.el7.centos              installed
[root@db01 ~]# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.59-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Any idea why it's installing 5.5.59?

More interesting output:

```
[root@db01 ~]# rpm -qf `which mysql`
MariaDB-client-5.5.59-1.el7.centos.x86_64
[root@db01 ~]# rpm -qa | fgrep 5.5.59
MariaDB-client-5.5.59-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-common-5.5.59-1.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Comment: Please execute `rpm -qf \`which mysql\`` as root and post the result.

Comment: Also, `rpm -qa | fgrep 5.5.59`, if it gives any result, would be interesting.

Comment: @Ned64 Added both commands to the answer.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Eh. Okay.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro My "Eh. Okay." comes from the fact that this is the first time I've downvoted your answer and you assume it is not. So no, that does not say anything about me. The reason I downvoted your answer is because you suggested to use `localinstall` instead of `install` while that is the exact same thing. I do appreciate help and answers.. I just think that specific one did not add anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the output from the requested commands, it seems you have

```
MariaDB-client-5.5.59-1.el7.centos.x86_64   and
MariaDB-common-5.5.59-1.el7.centos.x86_64
```

installed, which you would need to downgrade.  How to do this varies depending on your system, but please try

```
yum downgrade MariaDB-client-5.5.52-1 MariaDB-common-5.5.52-1
```

If that does not work, please try removing these packages (I am assuming here you can always restore them later) and re-installing the others:

```
rpm -e MariaDB-client-5.5.59-1 MariaDB-common-5.5.59-1
```

and then

```
yum reinstall mariadb
```

(and possibly the other two, let us know)

Comment: That is a very silly mistake. I just removed the packages and installed the respective RPM's.